# Where can I get pets from?

Tags: terraria

I have seen people in Terraria with gerbil pets, I really want one, but I don't know how to get pets.
Please help.

Answer (score 2):

There are currently *26* pets available for the PC version of Terraria. You can find a pet by getting them as a drop from successfully defeating certain bosses or finding them in certain chests. The Terraria Wiki covers [Pets](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Pets) more thoroughly, I recommend you check it out.

Comment: Also, some pets are seasonal prizes. For example, if you play around Halloween the mobs drop 'goodie bags', which have a chance of containing 'unlucky yarn', which summons a black cat pet. See terraria.gamepedia.com/Unlucky_Yarn